# Google Maps marker position after dragged

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, pass-by-reference

I may be missing some fundamental law in JavaScript here, quite possibly, but I have a question regarding the latlng position of a Google Maps marker after it is dragged.

I am successfully adding markers to a map, and assigning those added markers to a variable, or to be more precise, I'm using jQuery to add those markers to the `data` of the map's div element, using `jQuery.data()`.

Now, the problem I have arises when I drag those markers around the map. I understand the `dragend` event, and how to fire/capture it and it's data, including the new latlng position after the drag. That being said, I was of the understanding that objects in JavaScript are passed by reference, so what I can't understand is why the position of the marker reference stored in the element isn't updated to reflect the new position automatically?

I guess it could be one of the following:

1. Objects passed into the `data` of an element are duplicated, not passed by reference, and therefore a jQuery problem.
2. Google Maps doesn't automatically update the latlng positions of it's markers, stored in variables or `data` nodes, and therefore a Google Maps problem.
3. I have to physically fire the `dragend` event myself to update the position (sounds like an odd solution).

I'm basically querying this to see if I need to log it as an issue anywhere, or whether I'm just being an idiot. Any input from other hardened Google Mappers would really help me here.

Cheers in advance.

Comment: If I could retract a question without looking like an idiot, I would. It certainly does update the position, I just forgot to re-output into my JS Console. Duh.

Comment: I believe you can delete the question!

Comment: Too late now, my idiocy will remain forever.

Comment: :-)) no, you can flag it and ask admin to delete it :-)

Answer (score 7):

I've seen you have solved your problem but
maybe it's helpful for others reading this question.

Google Maps is overwriting the position of a Marker with a new LatLng-Object after dragend. If you store the position (LatLng-Object) of a marker in a variable, the variable holds a reference to the previously defined LatLng-Object. After the dragend the position of the marker gets updated but not the LatLng-Object itself.

Let's have a look at the following code:

```
var ll  = new google.maps.LatLng(52, 0.054);
var m   = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: ll,
    draggable: true,
    title: 'hello world'    
});

google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'dragend', function(ev){
    alert(ll.lat() + ' ' + ll.lng()); // always the same LatLng-Object...
    alert(m.getPosition()); // new LatLng-Object after dragend-event...
});
```

Comment: should have known you'd respond Adrian ;o)